# Редактор выдает undefined reference to `Test::Test(int, int, int, int)'

Tags: c++, отладка, clion

Test.cpp file

```
#include "Test.hpp"


template <typename T>
T Test::sum(T t1, T t2) {

}

Test::Test(int a, int b, int c, int d) : a(a), b(b), c(c), d(d) {};
```

Test.hpp file

```
#ifndef RO_TEST_HPP
#define RO_TEST_HPP

#define RO_MACRO_3 false
#define RO_MACRO_2 true


#define RO_MACRO_1  RO_MACRO_2 && RO_MACRO_3


class Test {


public:
    const static int st = 10;
    int a,b,c,d;

    Test(int a, int b, int c, int d);



    template <typename T>
    T sum(T t1, T t2);

};

#endif
```

Main.cpp file

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include "Test.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    Test * test  =  new Test(1,3,5,6);

    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};

    for (auto el : v) {
    }

    cout << "";


}
```

Comment: Это не редактор, а линковщик. Добавьте в проект test.cpp...

Comment: Благодарю, все сработало